# is there a jquery dropdown year selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

is there a jQuery plugin that creates automatically a dropdown year selector (that is a "select" element poulated with all years starting from current and dating back to a given year)?

I don't need day/month (otherwise i'd have used the datepicker), i just need the year!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 64, accepted):

What about just:

```
<select name="yearpicker" id="yearpicker"></select>
```

And then:

```
for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 1900; i--)
{
    $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
}
```

Comment: Not everything **has** to be a plugin (though, I must admit, that can be helpful in itself). +1

Comment: In the end i implemented a "server side version" of your idea because a also needed to populate it, but it was excatly what i needed!thx again

Comment: Hi, Jimmy, could you please tell me how to use same year picker in Codeigniter's default select dropdown-  Codeigniter's dropdown select is liek this>>  <? echo form_dropdown('salary_month', $options,'', 'class="medium required"'  );?> Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: @Srijon that's sort of outside the scope of *this* question, you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: @Jimmy Sawczuk .. sorry my mistake .:-)

Comment: I find that some browsers don't like the self closing tags, so will favor '[option][/option]' (replacing the brackets of course).

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping around the code into jQuery plugin to select years between start  and end year:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn,{

    /*
    ** Year selection plugin
    ** Sample usage
    ** $('#yearpicker').years(2007, 2017);
    **
    ** HTML
    ** <select name="yearpicker" id="yearpicker"></select>
    */
    years: function(start, end) {
        for (i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            $(this).append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Jimmy Sawczuk's solution - what if you also needed to process feedback data into a form page where a previous selection needed to be loaded/selected.

A variable holding the user's previous selection can be used in an if statement to dynamically  assign the "Selected" attribute like so:

```
for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 1900; i--)
{
 if(userselection == i){
 $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).attr("selected","selected").html(i));
 } else {    
 $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

datepicker has the minViewMode option. In my case I used it for date ranges in years:

JavaScript:
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
      minViewMode: 2,
      format: 'yyyy'
    });

HTML:

```
<div class="input-daterange date"id="DataRange">
  <input type="text"class="input-small"/>
    <span class="add-on">to</span>
  <input type="text"class="input-small"/>
</div>
```